# access shared folders from unix to windows

Tags: unix

how to access a shared folder in unix system connected through LAN from windows using IP address

Answer (score 3):

Install [samba server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_%28software%29) and you have done.

Comment: i have linux system's ip address, user name and password and putty installed in my system.. how to proceed

Comment: this is other question, if you don't have enough skills to install some application via bash you must ask question on superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

As you have Putty, you can use is as an SSH client and connect to your server in an SSH remote session.

Your server must have an SSH server to answer to the requests. You can use OpenSSH on unix-like architectures (linux, bsd, ...). Depending on whether your server is running a distribution from the Debian family (Debian/Ubuntu/Mint/...) or RedHat (RedHat/CentOS/Fedora) family, you will have to enter one of these two commands in the terminal to install the OpenSSH server.

`sudo apt-get install openssh-server`

`sudo yum install openssh-server`

There are already many tutorials on the net, about how to open an SSH session on a remote server using Putty.

Nota bene: OpenSSH already incluses sftp daemon if you want to transfer files in SFTP.

Other solution to transfer files is using an FTP server and client (not recommended for security) or preferably FTPS (FTP+SSL) server and client. 
However, the trend nowadays is using SFTP (Secure FTP over SSH) which is a different protocol than FTP. SSH also means that you can pass commands to the remote machine.